# Print statement

Tags: java, printing

New to Java.

Does anyone know how I can print the following output:

```
The sum of the digits is 3 + 0 + 4 + 5 + 8 = 20
```

This is my print line:

```
System.out.print("The sum of the digits is: " + num1 + num2 + num3 + num4 + num5 + sum);
```

I want to get the `+` sign to display, but for some reason I get errors.

Any assistance is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

There is a difference between `+` and `"+"`. The first is used to combine Strings in this case and the second is a String with the value of a plus sign.
So a simple plus in a String would look like this:

```
num1 + " + " + num2 + " = " + solution
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. I changed it but I get a different error now - Syntax error on token.   This is the change I made: System.out.println("The sum of the digits is: " + num1 + " + " num2 + " + " num3 + " + " num4 + " + " num5 + " = " sum);

Comment: @garro12 you are missing a  + before num2 , 
this is the correct ans :
  System.out.print(
                "The sum of the digits is: " + num1 + " + " + num2 + " + " + num3 + " + " + num4 + " + " + num5 + " = "
                        + sum);

Comment: You missed some `+` between `"+"` and `numX`. Note that you have to put a `+` between every part, reguardless of written String or variable.